# specify R package path (Android)

Tags: android

Is it possible to specify the package path for R.class ?

The R class package is using the package path specified in the AndroidManifest.xml

The reason I ask that because I am trying to deploy the same codebase to different application.

The difference between the apps will be the image and text. while code logic remain the same.

To deploy the same code to multiple apps require unique package name for each app in the AndroidManifest.xml.

The problem is when the package name change, R is regenerated. All java file import for R is invalid with the outdated package. And I have to modify each java file for the R.class import. If I can specify a common path for R. This problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need to go every screen to change import com.packagename.R.

1) press ctrl+h

[image]

2) Select "File Search" tab and enter your old packagename to search

3) Press "Replace" button

[image]

4) Give your new package name to replace with.

5) Clean build and enjoy.

**If your using Linux machine single command do a trick**

```
find yourprojectpath  -type f -exec sed -i 's/com.oldpackage.name/com.new.packagename/g' {} \\;
```